# Putting text on TQFT diagrams

Tags: tikz-pgf, tqft

I'd like put text over cobordism diagrams created with the `tqft` package. Unfortunately, I don't know much about TikZ so I have been getting by with trial and error, but this has finally got me stumped. Ideally, I would like to have something like the picture below:

[image]

I am able to produce the diagram with the following code, but I have tried using the `pic text` option and nothing came out of it. Additionally, I would like to annotate the boundaries, so if you could provide an example of that too, I would be very grateful. Thanks!

```
    \begin{tikzpicture}[tqft/cobordism/.style={draw},
         tqft/view from=outgoing, tqft/boundary separation=30pt,
         tqft/cobordism height=40pt, tqft/circle x radius=8pt,
         tqft/circle y radius=3pt, tqft/every boundary component/.style={draw,rotate=90}]

        \pic[tqft/cylinder,rotate=90,name=a,anchor={(1,0)}];
        \pic[tqft,
            incoming boundary components=0,
            outgoing boundary components=2,
            rotate=90,name=b,anchor={(0,0)}];
        \pic[tqft,
            incoming boundary components=2,
            outgoing boundary components=0,
            rotate=90,name=c,at=(a-outgoing boundary)];
        \pic[tqft/cylinder,rotate=90,at=(b-outgoing boundary 2)];
    \end{tikzpicture}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use tha anchors for the components to locate a `\node` with the desired label:

[image]

The code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tqft}

\begin{document}

 \begin{tikzpicture}[tqft/cobordism/.style={draw},
         tqft/view from=outgoing, tqft/boundary separation=30pt,
         tqft/cobordism height=40pt, tqft/circle x radius=8pt,
         tqft/circle y radius=3pt, tqft/every boundary component/.style={draw,rotate=90}]

        \pic[tqft/cylinder,rotate=90,name=a,anchor={(1,0)}];
        \pic[tqft,
            incoming boundary components=0,
            outgoing boundary components=2,
            rotate=90,name=b,anchor={(0,0)}];
        \pic[tqft,
            incoming boundary components=2,
            outgoing boundary components=0,
            rotate=90,name=c,at=(a-outgoing boundary)];
        \pic[tqft/cylinder,rotate=90,name=d,at=(b-outgoing boundary 2)];
        \node at ([xshift=-4pt]b-between outgoing 1 and 2) {$\xi$};
        \node[pin=20:$\delta_{2}$] at (c-incoming boundary 2) {};
        \node[pin=-20:$\delta_{1}$] at (c-incoming boundary 1) {};
    \end{tikzpicture} 

\end{document}
```